# Illustrated hilchot Kiddush Hachodesh

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, calendar, rambam, astronomy

I remember seeing about 20 years ago a beautiful annotated commentary on Rambam's hilchos kiddush hachodesh, with extensive illustrations and calculations, explained according to both ancient and modern astronomy. But I have never been able to find it again. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: This sounds nice. I hope someone answers this. IIRC, Art Scroll Masechet Rosh Hashanna has some illustrations regarding the moon's shape and position. You may want to check Steinzaltz, as well, as he tends to have detailed explanations. I haven't seen Steinzaltz, itself, but I'm making an educated guess that he may have some illustrations.

Answer (score 5):

http://kiddushhachodesh.net/ has many videos decently done.

Comment: thanks for the link , I happened to just finish Hilchos kiddush hachodesh this shabbas and these videos really gave me more of a solid background of the calculations present ed by the Rambam,so thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

New web book presentation of the Rambam’s “Laws Of The New Moon” - Hilchot Kiddush Hachodesh illustrate the Laws with dynamic 3D graphics. And Video lesson for each chapter.

[To Kiddush HaChodesh site](http://kiddushhachodesh.net)
[image: Lunar Subsequent Conjunction]

Comment: just saw this beautiful site. thank you very much!